# Can you use nodejs along side react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I would like to know if it is not only possible to use node js on a react native app, but also if it is viable. By viable, I would like to know if there is anything limiting the use of the app or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nodejs is ideal backend for react and react-native.
We have been using it for many years now and does not seem to have any limitation.
It is more of a dependent question on how and what you want to build.

Have a look at below link for some good explaination.

https://www.simform.com/use-nodejs-with-react/

Comment: but doesn't react have its own backend?